# Node.js on Heroku - Memcached Usage

Tags: node.js, heroku, memcached

I set up my Heroku instance to have Memcached, so now I have the MEMCACHE_PASSWORD, MEMCACHE_SERVERS and MEMCACHE_USERNAME env variables. How do I use them with any of the existing node.js memcached libraries? They all seem to take in just a host and port (I'm assuming the port is the default 11211?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there is no Node library available that supports this scenario. Heroku's memcached instances use [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) for authentication. None of the currently available libraries support this, and [there doesn't seem to be much momentum to add support, either](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/15).

If you want to try to implement this yourself, it might be worth taking a look at [sasljs](https://github.com/nikhilm/sasljs), which is a Node binding around [GNU SASL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/). Your best bet would probably be to fork [node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) and add SASL support there.

Comment: sasljs only implements the server side of SASL, so it doesn't help for this use case :(  
  
I would be very happy to add SASL support to node-memcached, and 3rd-Eden seems [happy to adopt it](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/15), but I'm afraid I have no idea where to start...

Comment: @NearPrivman You're correct, sasljs only does the server-side. However, it binds GSASL, which can also be used for a SASL client (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/manual/gsasl.html#Examples). One option would be to fork sasljs and add bindings for whatever is necessary from GSASL to implement a SASL client. Not a trivial task, admittedly.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, both Memcache addons on Heroku only support the binary protocol. I wrote a library, [MemJS](http://github.com/alevy/memjs), that works with these addons (supports SASL with the binary protocol and recognizes the Heroku environment variables out of the box).

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache

`var client = new memcache.Client('11211', 'http://xxxx:xxxxx@mc10.ec2.northscale.net');`

Comment: It seems that node-memcache depends on node.js >=0.6 while Heroku requires version 0.4.7.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Node 0.6 either. @Radoslav have you tried this or are you just guessing here?
I'm getting an `[Error: getaddrinfo EFAULT]`

Comment: BTW, @Jusso, Heroku now supports Node 0.6 as well, you just need to specify it in your package.json https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

Comment: From the author of this lib (Tim Eggert): "I'm not sure how anybody could have used node-memcache with SASL since the memcached docs say that SASL only works with the binary protocol. node-memcache currently only uses the Text-Protocol and so shouldn't be able to communicate with it. (see http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto)"